# Launch app from app in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have written two apps with Xamarin: CallerApp and CalleeApp. If a button in CallerApp is clicked, the CalleeApp should be started (if not started already) and become visible.

On top of the MainActivity of the CalleeApp, I have defined the intent like:

```
 [IntentFilter(new [] { Intent.ActionView }, DataScheme="abcdef", Categories=new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.FormsApplicationActivity
 {
      ...
 }
```

In the CallerApp, when the button is clicked, I do:

```
 var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(abcdef://));
 Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

I then run CalleeApp, which is then deployed on the device and started.
I then run CallerApp, which is then deployed on the device and started.
If I then click the button, I get the message: "No apps can perform this action".

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Note: if I try to launch the Maps application as in the example at http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/intent/launch_the_map_application/, I get the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just got it working, but not by changing the code. The current date and time of the development machine was wrong, once I corrected it, it started working!

Answer (score 0):

It must me solved using an Intent, the intent try to launch the package you want by using the PackageManager class, simply this:

```
Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.company_name.app_name");
StartActivity(intent);
```

Don't forget to replace "com.company_name.app_name" with the name of the app package you want to run. If app package is not installed it will raise an exception, then you can ask user to install the app, open Play Store and wathever.